# Rails - which is better practice: Resoureful routing or HTTP verb constraints?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there are recommended practice between using resourceful routing and using HTTP verb constraints?

for example, which is better:

```
resources :posts, only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :comments, only: [:index]
end
```

or

```
scope '/posts' do
  get '' => 'posts#index'
  get '/:id' => 'posts#show'
  get '/comments' => 'posts#comments'
end
```

EDIT: to be clear, I'm asking specifically for cases where I only need 1 or 2 actions.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

Comment: I prefer the first one.

Comment: will better to do this resources :posts, only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :comments, only: [:index]
end
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html

Comment: I did read Rails' guide; I felt it wasn't clear specifically when I end up always overriding the defaults with "only", and especially when I only need 1 or 2 actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the first one. It is rails convention to use their helpers in your routes file. This accomplished a few things:

1. Someone reading your routes file will come from a common understanding of what exactly is going on without reading each manually defined route individually.
2. It is more concise. If you are including all of the verbs, you can get away with a nice and clean `resources :posts`. If you are only including one, you only have to specify one option using `:only` or `:except`. Nested routes really explodes this point.
3. It's the convention as defined in [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org) as sevenseacat pointed out.

With libraries such as rails, there are commonly guides as to the expected and preferred implementation of the code. Rails' guide is found at [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org). You should be comfortable and in the habit of going to their documentation first, especially with topics such as this to find answers about what approach is preferred.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to explain rather than simply provide a link. I did read Rails' guide; please understand that I felt it wasn't clear specifically when I end up always overriding the defaults with "only", and especially when I only need 1 or 2 actions.